How to rescore Elasticsearch results using semantic search with custom boosting conditions?
I am using Elasticsearch's ELSER inference model to perform semantic searches. I need to rescore the search results based on specific conditions: spotlighted documents should be at the top, followed by verified documents, and finally sorted by the highest votes in descending order.
Here is the current Elasticsearch query I am using for semantic search:
GET business-index/_search?filter_path=hits.hits._source.title,hits.hits._source.subtitle,hits.hits._source.categorySearch,hits.hits._source.spotlight,hits.hits._source.verified,hits.hits._source.votes,hits.hits._source.createdAt
{
  "query": {
    "semantic": {
      "query": "broken pipes",
      "field": "elser"
    }
  }
}

I also have an example of a more complex query that works but is based on a different search type:
GET business-index/_search?filter_path=hits.hits._source.title,hits.hits._source.subtitle,hits.hits._source.categorySearch,hits.hits._source.spotlight,hits.hits._source.verified,hits.hits._source.votes,hits.hits._source.createdAt,aggregations,hits.hits._explanation&explain=false
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "more_like_this": {
                "fields": ["title", "subtitle"], 
                "like": "food",  
                "min_term_freq": 1, 
                "max_query_terms": 12
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "title.keyword": {
                  "value": "food",
                  "boost": 30 
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "spotlight": true
            }
          },
          "weight": 20
        },
        {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "verified": true
            }
          },
          "weight": 10
        },
        {
          "field_value_factor": {
            "field": "votes",
            "factor": 1,
            "modifier": "log1p",
            "missing": 0
          },
          "weight": 20
        }
      ],
      "boost_mode": "sum",
      "score_mode": "sum"
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "_score": "desc"
    },
    {
      "votes": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "aggs": {
    "categories": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "categorySearch.keyword", 
        "size": 10
      }
    },
    "users": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "upvotedBy.name.keyword", 
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}

How can I modify my semantic search query to include rescoring based on the following fields: spotlight, verified, and votes, with votes sorted in descending order?
Here are my index mappings for reference:
{
  "business-index": {
    "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "addedBy": {
          "type": "object"
        },
        "added_by": {
          "properties": {
            "user": {
              "properties": {
                "name": {
                  "type": "text",
                  "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                      "type": "keyword",
                      "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                  }
                },
                "profile_image": {
                  "properties": {
                    "url": {
                      "type": "text",
                      "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                          "type": "keyword",
                          "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "categorySearch": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "category_search": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "createdAt": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "created_at": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "elser": {
          "type": "semantic_text",
          "inference_id": ".elser-2-elasticsearch",
          "model_settings": {
            "task_type": "sparse_embedding"
          }
        },
        "free": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "googleMapsLink": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "google_maps_link": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "id": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "location": {
          "type": "geo_point"
        },
        "logo": {
          "properties": {
            "url": {
              "type": "text"
            }
          }
        },
        "marketSegment": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "market_segment": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "phoneNumber": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "phone_number": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "regionSearch": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "region_search": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "spotlight": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "subtitle": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          },
          "copy_to": [
            "elser"
          ]
        },
        "title": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            },
            "suggest": {
              "type": "completion",
              "analyzer": "simple",
              "preserve_separators": true,
              "preserve_position_increments": true,
              "max_input_length": 50
            }
          },
          "copy_to": [
            "elser"
          ]
        },
        "upvotedBy": {
          "properties": {
            "id": {
              "type": "long"
            },
            "name": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
            "profileImage": {
              "properties": {
                "url": {
                  "type": "text",
                  "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                      "type": "keyword",
                      "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "upvoted_by": {
          "properties": {
            "id": {
              "type": "integer"
            },
            "name": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
            "profile_image": {
              "properties": {
                "url": {
                  "type": "text",
                  "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                      "type": "keyword",
                      "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "verified": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "votes": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "whatsAppLink": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "whatsAppNumberUrl": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "whatsapp_link": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "whatsapp_number_url": {
          "type": "text"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


Check elasticsearch rrf. it can help.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/rrf.html

heya, so i looked at that but how does that solve my issue? Can you give an example because i cant figure it out
